# What loads the classes in rt.jar?

Tags: java

I want to know whether it is possible to specify an alternative to rt.jar to be loaded instead of rt.jar. So my question is, what loads rt.jar and is it possible to specify an alternative jar to be loaded instead of rt.jar?

Comment: it's called bootstap loader and yes you can do so: `java -Xbootclasspath/p:pathToyourJarZ`

Comment: @bestsss Why post an answer in the comments section? :)

Comment: It's very simple enough, doesn't require any brain activity and it's a single sentence in the end. Then I have to make it community-wiki to prevent rep. influx... so much job over nothing.

Answer (score 0):

rt.jar is the core runtime jars of the JRE. RT stands for runtime!

Why do you want to override it? Explain in detail..

Comment: no need to explain, it's a standard option (or non-standard due to -X but widely supported)

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at the [Java Extension Mechanism](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/ext/index.html).